What is the genesis of the particle "вряд ли"?
The parts of it seem kinda unrelated to the actual meaning, no?

The semantic development of вряд is as such:

"Near, nearby, next to" (whence also the modern Russian рядом):


Да с ними ж тутъ в ряд стали немецких два полковника с салдатами — в полку у них солдат 6000. [Федор Иванов Порошин. Повесть об азовском осадном сидении донских казаков (1641—1642)]
Next to them two foreign commanders and their troops took position, their regiment numbering six thousand soldiers.



"Together with"


Ему ж за конотопскую службу с ево братьею в ряд сто чети, денег десять рублев. // [Боярская книга (1658)]
For his service in Konotop, together with his people, (grant him) hundred quarters (~60 hectares) of land and a sum of ten rubles.



"On par with"


А тягло государево с того деревенского участка н[а нынешней] год и впреть платити ему Артюшки со крестьяны в ряд. [Купчая на деревенский участок в Лычноостровской волости, проданный Степаном Самойловым и Прохором Самойловым Артемию Чеккоеву (1670.01)]
And that the royal tax be paid, from this year on, by Artyushka (Artem) on par with the peasants.



"Barely enough"


И нынѣ у насъ, великій государь, толки врядъ будетъ хлѣба на се лѣто; а нынѣ, великій государь, время служивое, и мы боимся, что будетъ хлѣбъ дорогъ. [Отписка патриарху Никону от архимандрита Иверского монастыря Дионисия (1657.04)]
And now, O Grand Prince, we only have barely enough grain for this year, and these days it's the period of state service summons, and we are worried that grain will become expensive.



"Enough"


А впредь бы вамъ къ намъ, великому господину, о своихъ монастырскихъ дѣлахъ не писать: врядъ намъ и безъ вашихъ хлопотъ. [Грамота патриарха Никона архимандриту Иверского монастыря Филофею о высылке в Воскресенский монастырь к прощению Иеромонаха Досифея и прихожанина старца Александра и о воспрещении писать патриарху о монастырских делах (1664.08.01—1664.08.05)]
From now on, you are not to write us, your Great Prince, about your monasterial business. We have enough (on our plate) even without your troubles.




The set expressoin вряд он сделает ли has thus started out as a rhetoric question: "will he do enough?" (with the implied answer that no, he won't).
Later, the particle ли moved after вряд, and the resulting particle вряд ли "unlikely, hardly, barely" had lost is figurative meaning and fossilized in its current form.

Sounds very much contrived. To me at least

@Alex: sounds contrived to me too, and it's not even the most far-fetched looking example of a semantic shift.

@Quassnoi just as contrived as semantic shift of verb "contrive", its progentior and derivative "contrived" itself. It's a word that defines itself by own history.
